How to fetch the dynamic value from the github action and use it further
New to github action and I am trying to fetch a variable from the previous step and use it further how  to do it ?
My sample YAML File:
---
  name: Snyk Scan for Test
  on:
    push:
      branches:
        - main
  jobs:
    security:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: Checkout code
          uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Install dependencies
          run : npm i
        - name: Run Snyk to check for vulnerabilities
          id  : snyk_scan
          uses: snyk/actions/node@master
          env :
            SNYK_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SNYK_TOKEN }}
          with:
            command: monitor
        - name: Extract Snyk URL
          id: extract_snyk_url
          run: echo "URL=VALUE" >> $(echo '${{ steps.snyk_scan.outputs.stdout }}' | grep -o 'https://app.snyk.io/org<test_repo>/history/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\+')

From the above file when I am running it I am getting the following result,
Run snyk/actions/node@master
/usr/bin/docker run --name snyksnyknode_20650d --label ab5c16 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "SNYK_TOKEN" -e "INPUT_COMMAND" -e "INPUT_ARGS" -e "INPUT_JSON" -e "FORCE_COLOR" -e "SNYK_INTEGRATION_NAME" -e "SNYK_INTEGRATION_VERSION" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RESULTS_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/<code_repo>/<code_repo>":"/github/workspace" snyk/snyk:node  "snyk" "monitor" ""
Monitoring /github/workspace (<code_repo> Test Suite)...
Explore this snapshot at https://app.snyk.io/org/<repo_details>/history/566241c0-c5j2-4506-a86b-8e61jp4783b3
Tip: Detected multiple supported manifests (1), use --all-projects to scan all of them at once.
Notifications about newly disclosed issues related to these dependencies will be emailed to you.

`
I am trying to fetch the url value from Explore this snapshot at https://app.snyk.io/org/<repo_details>/history/566241c0-c5j2-4506-a86b-8e61jp4783b3. How do it ? I am trying but not able to fetch it.
Tried with set-output but is it depricating, anyway I can solve it ?

Based on this documentation, I think the line you want is run: echo "URL=$(echo '${{ steps.snyk_scan.outputs.stdout }}' | grep -o 'https://app.snyk.io/org<test_repo>/history/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\+')" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

yes, Michele, I want to get that value.

The line I proposed is slightly different from yours, which I think is wrong. Can you try running that and seeing if you can use the $URL variable in a following step?

To pass a value from one step to another, you need to execute the following in the first step:
echo "<VARIABLE>=<VALUE>" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

And then use it in the second step with the following syntax:
${{ steps.<STEP-ID>.outputs.<VARIABLE> }}

In your case, the "extract_snyk_url" step will work (the way it is) if you add the following in the "snyk_scan" step:
echo "stdout=<URL>" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

